# inserting into auto-increment column in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a table in sqlite (in java), it has 3 columns the ID is autoicremented.

`stat.executeUpdate("create table Info (ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, age int, point int);");`

when I want to insert in that table I have this function

```
DataBase.databaseInsertInfoTable(data.age, data.point);
```

and

```
  public static void databaseInfoTable(int age,int point) throws Exception {

  PreparedStatement prepInfo = conn.prepareStatement(
     "insert into Info (age, point)values (?, ?);");
        prepInfo.setInt(2, age);
        prepInfo.setInt(3, point);
        prepInfo.addBatch();
        prepInfo.executeBatch();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
       prepInfo.close();
  }
```

I have an error which says bad parameter I wanted to insert null value for ID but it does not work too so I omit the ID in insertion! what should I do?

Comment: What is the signature of prepareStatement method?

Comment: Ignore the above, sorry.

Comment: It still does not work if you have an idea please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert a null value for an AUTOINCREMENT field. Remove the semi-colon at the end of the statement and see if that works for you.

EDIT: try this.

```
public static void databaseInfoTable(int age,int point) throws Exception {
  PreparedStatement prepInfo = conn.prepareStatement(
     "insert into Info (age, point)values (?, ?)");
        prepInfo.setInt(1, age);
        prepInfo.setInt(2, point);
        prepInfo.addBatch();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
prep.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
  }
```